# Using processing.runalg in python script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to run the following python script:

```
from qgis.core import *
import sys
import os
import qgis.utils
from qgis.analysis import *

app = QgsApplication([],True,"")

# supply path to where is your qgis installed
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/", True)

# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()

sys.path.append("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins")
import processing

layer3 = QgsVectorLayer("../output/precinctsZipcodes.shp", "intersect", "ogr")
if layer3.isValid():
    print "Loaded layer 3"
else:
    print "Layer 3 failed to load!"

processing.runalg("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", layer3, 0, "../output/precinctsZipcodesArea.shp")

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

However, the line `processing.runalg("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", layer3, 0, "../output/precinctsZipcodesArea.shp")` isn't saving any output. The strange thing is that this syntax works when I run it directly in the python console. Does anybody know what might be happening?

Comment: Along with what @gcarrillo has mentioned with changing paths and such, try replacing `processing.runalg` with `general.runalg`.

Comment: You're right Joseph, `general.runalg()` is the way I call QGIS processing algorithms from standalone scripts, as you can also see in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of what could be happening there, but the next code snippet has worked for me on my GNU/Linux machine:

```
# Prepare the environment
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/home/germap/.qgis2/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

# Run the algorithm
layerInput = QgsVectorLayer('world_adm0.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
general.runalg("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", layerInput, 0, "tmp.shp")

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

I successfully got the `tmp.shp` file saved in the folder from which I run the script. Could you give it a try? Just adjust QGIS prefix and other paths to reflect your system configuration.