# Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts without crashing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqt, python.exe-stopped-working

I am new to the PyQGIS API.

For developing I use my [Spyder IDE with QGIS and GRASS modules](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164261/50772). In order to make my script executable I just run my code with the QGIS python.exe in my bat file. This all works so far. However, none of the [PyQGIS cookbook code snippets](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-application) worked and for some reason the only thing that did the job was [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/169247/50772) I could adapt (posted several times by user @Germán Carrillo). Also it took me quite a while to figure out that [the order how you import your modules matters](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Unable-to-use-system-PyQt-alongside-QGIS-2-16-td5276162.html) (`PyQt4.QtGui` before `qgis.core` breaks the code).

So for example I want to create a simple hillshade from a DEM. This works with my code from my Spyder IDE if I run it once. When I run it another time, it causes python to stop working. When I run it as a bat file, I still get the hillshade, but again I get the message 'python.exe has stopped working'. This is not clean and helpfull at all if I want to develop something more complex and let it run in an automated way. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172844/using-standalone-pyqgis-application-qgsapplication-initqgis-fails) didn't work for me unfortunately. Also, either way the `processing` module copies its folder structure (only the folders though, not its content) into my working directory together with a qgis-auth.db file. This also seems not clean at all.

Here my code with a download link provided to a small DEM sample file:

```
# get small DEM from https://github.com/GeospatialPython/Learn/blob/master/dem.zip

# Prepare the environment
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
print "QGIS successfully Initialised"

# Prepare processing framework 
# https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/how-can-i-access-processing-with-python
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins') # Folder where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing algorithms, etc.
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer("dem.asc", "hillshade")
rasterLyr.isValid()

general.runalg("gdalogr:hillshade", rasterLyr, 1, False, False, 1.0, 1.0, 315.0, 45.0,"qgis_hs.tif")

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.quit()
```

Again, this code work in my Spyder IDE when run once, but causes python to stop working when run another time. It also works when run from a bat file, but also crashes my python.exe. Any ideas? That way I can't replace ArcPy with PyQGIS unfortunately.

---

The problem definitely seems to be related to how `QApplication` and `QgsApplication` is initialised (or not correctly ended?). I just tried an NDVI calculation without the messy `processing` library and I still get the same crashing errors.

---

Yes, most definitely a Qt problem that is caused by not properly closing the app. [This](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2970#issue-132220741) was [reported](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2970#issuecomment-181817781) quite [frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041259/python-kernel-crashes-after-closing-an-pyqt4-gui-application). Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions work for me (or I just don't know how to implement correctly).

Answer (score 4):

> The problem definitely seems to be related to how QApplication and QgsApplication is initialised

Yes, the thing is: `QgsApplication` is a subclass of PyQt's `QApplication`, so basically you do not need (and should not) instantiate a `QApplication` here, instead just use the `QgsApplication`.

The problem can also be related to the `QgsApplication.exitQgis()` as it seems to cause a sigsegv on the exit. Using `QgsApplication.exit()` solve it for me

Try this:

```
import sys
# Import only what you're going to use
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsRasterLayer

# You can add this path to your system's environment so you don't have to type it here
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
import processing

# This is a 'fake' iface since we are not using a interface here
class DummyIface(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.destCrs = None


# Pass QgsApplication to an object and you can use it just like a QApplication
app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.initQgis()
print "QGIS successfully Initialised"

# I took the freedom to change the way you used processing here, just to be sure it will work
processing.classFactory(DummyIface())

rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer("dem.asc", "hillshade")
# An assertion check, because we do not want to continue if we do not have this layer right
assert rasterLyr.isValid()

processing.runalg("gdalogr:hillshade", rasterLyr, 1, False, False, 1.0, 1.0, 315.0, 45.0,"qgis_hs.tif")

app.exit()
```

sidenote: you may have problems with the processing module as it tries to set a progress for you while you have no interface. Have a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235031/pyqgis-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-progress-bar-in-the-processing-tool/237282#237282) if that is the case

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll just sit it out and use GDAL in the meantime...apparently QGIS 3.0 should make using PyQGIS much less of a hassle: http://nyalldawson.net/2017/05/the-inaugural-qgis-australia-hackfest-noosa-2017/